# pandas read_csv how to deal with space within a column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to read a txt file into python using pandas read-csv. Each column is separated with a space so I tried sep=' '.

However, one column contains texts that have spaces in them. A typical row looks like this:

New York 123 I love the city 321

It has four columns but the third column "I love the city" has space in it so pandas is going to seperate the words. Any idea how to read this type of file? Thanks!

Comment: CSV means ,you can make it as comma-separated and then use read_csv. This workaround makes it simple.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. How do I make it as comma-seperated then? If I change the entire txt file, that's going to be a lot of work.

Comment: "*this type of file*" - the type is "broken", send it back and get it created as a structured file (proper CSV or something). Otherwise you're going to have to guess based on something else (are columns 2 and 4 actually numbers?) or fix it by hand.

Comment: drop the file into a text editor, figure out regex, run some replace functions. you got this.

Comment: Are there always digits in-between text blobs?